# Recursive mergesort only returns first half of ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, mergesort

For CS homework, I am trying to use the merge sort method to sort an ArrayList. Here is my code:

```
public static LinkedList<Object> merge (LinkedList<Object> lsta, LinkedList<Object> lstb) {
    LinkedList<Object> result = new LinkedList<Object>();
    LinkedList<Object> lstaNew = (LinkedList<Object>) lsta.clone();
    LinkedList<Object> lstbNew = (LinkedList<Object>) lstb.clone();
    while(lstaNew.size()>0||lstaNew.size()>0) {
        if(lstaNew.size()>0&&lstbNew.size()>0) {
            if( ((Comparable) lstaNew.getFirst()).compareTo(lstbNew.getFirst()) < 0 ) {
                result.add(lstaNew.getFirst());
                lstaNew.remove();
            }
            else {
                result.add(lstbNew.getFirst());
                lstbNew.remove();
            }
        }
        else if(lstaNew.size()>0) {
            result.add(lstaNew.getFirst());
            lstaNew.remove();
        }
        else {
            result.add(lstbNew.getFirst());
            lstbNew.remove();
        }
    }
    return result;
}

public static LinkedList<Object> sort (LinkedList<Object> lst) {
    if (lst.size() <= 1) return lst;
    LinkedList<Object> left = new LinkedList<Object>();
    LinkedList<Object> right = new LinkedList<Object>();
    int midpoint = lst.size()/2;
    for (int i=0;i<midpoint;i++) left.add(lst.get(i));
    for (int i=midpoint;i<lst.size();i++) right.add(lst.get(i));
    return merge(sort(left),sort(right));
}
```

However, in my results I am only getting the first half of the list. I have looked at other examples of merge sort online, and my code seems to be similar. What am I doing wrong? A pointer in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your code -

```
while(lstaNew.size()>0||lstaNew.size()>0) {
```

Should have been -

```
while(lstaNew.size()>0||lstbNew.size()>0) {
```